# Определение речевой ошибки. Стилистика.

Tags: стилистика

подскажите пожалуйста::: Исправьте предложения, устраняя лексические ошибки. Укажите разновидности ошибок: выбор слова без учета его значения, речевая избыточность (тавтология или плеоназм), нарушение лексической сочетаемости, неверное использование паронимов, синонимов, антонимов.
1.  Наконец-то этот ребус распутан: задержаны трое бандитов, нигде не работающих, неоднократно судимых за тяжкие преступления. 2. Подсудимый сначала его избил, а потом травмировал. 3. Прошу вас разделить мою квартиру, так как прекратилось бракосочетание. 4. Прибывшему сотруднику милиции подсудимая оказала сопротивление, выталкивая его корпусом. 5. Сторонники либерализации цен получили значимый перевес голосов. 6. Первые годы их семейной жизни были счастливыми, это была настоящая лебединая песня. 7. Допрошенный в качестве обвиняемого Шмаев в предъявленном ему обвинении виновным себя признал полностью. 8. Этот факт оказался в поле внимания сотрудников милиции. 9. На сцену выходит очередная претендентка на звание чемпионки этого конкурса красоты. 10. Молодой вундеркинд был известен по всей стране.Спасибо))))))

Comment: Так подскажите или исправьте (сделайте за меня)?

Comment: Ларf, подскажиите))

Answer (score 1):

1.Наконец-то этот ребус разгадан : задержаны трое бандитов, нигде не работающих, неоднократно судимых за тяжкие преступления.-нарушение лексической сочетаемости

2.Подсудимый нанёс травмы во время избиения. - речевая избыточность

3.Прошу вас разделить мою квартиру, так как  наш брак распался.-нарушение лексической сочетаемости

4.Прибывшему сотруднику милиции подсудимая оказала сопротивление, выталкивая его всем телом. - выбор слова без учёта его значения.

5.Сторонники либерализации цен получили значительный перевес голосов. -выбор слова без учёта его значения.

6.Первые годы их семейной жизни были счастливыми, это была настоящая лебединая песня. выбор фразеологизма без учёта его значения.

7.Допрошенный в качестве обвиняемого Шмаев  виновным себя признал полностью.- тавтология

8.Этот факт оказался в поле зрения сотрудников милиции.-нарушена лексич. сочетаемость

9.На сцену выходит очередная претендентка на звание победительницы этого конкурса красоты. -выбор слова без учёта его значения.

10.Вундеркинд был известен по всей стране.-речевая избыточность

Comment: Людмила, спасибо огромное)))

Comment: Допрошенный в качестве обвиняемого Шмаев виновным себя признал полностью.- тавтология 
А что считать тавтологией?

Comment: В предложении "Допрошенный в качестве обвиняемого Шмаев в предъявленном ему обвинении виновным себя признал полностью".- обвиняемый -обвинении. Разве нет?

Comment: Тут, имхо, другое. "Признал виновным в обвинении" - тут или полная несочетаемость либо, как минимум, неверное управление. 
Признал себя виновным в хранении наркотиков - это понятно.
"Но виновным в обвинении" - это что-то марсианское. 
Я не соображу как это звучит правильно на юридическом языке, я бы сказал "Полностью признал себя виновным ***по сути*** предъявленного обвинения".

Comment: В ходе допроса обвиняемого Шмаева, вина, в инкриминируемых ему преступлениях, им была признана полностью.

Comment: Ну это - для протокола. В остальных случаях уже перебор.

Comment: behemothus, в задании было только о речевых ошибках, о грамматике (нарушение управления)нет, а тавтология  "обвинении - обвиняемый " бросается в глаза сразу, несочетаемость (корявость фразы) убирается при исправлении этой ошибки, т.к. приходится перестраивать всё предложение